# How do I get a specific element with the only difference being the height attribute

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have multiple elements that are exactly the same, the only difference is one has the attribute `height=0` while the other has `height=SOME NUMBER GREATER THAN ZERO`. The positions of these elements also changes so using `eq` or `first` won't work after a while.

The only solution I can think of that is not really a solution is doing

`cy.get('.className[height=StaticValue]').click()` and then changing that whenever it changes or using eq.

Is there any better way I could do this?

Comment: change the code that alters the attribute to use/toggle a class? If not, you are stuck looking at attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each()` to loop through all the elements and then using `$el.attr('height')` you check which elements have the value of height 0 or greater than 0.

```
cy.get('selector').each(($el) => {
    if (parseInt($el.attr('height')) == 0) {
        //Do something with element with height 0
        cy.wrap($el).click() // If you want to click the element with height 0
    } else if (parseInt($el.attr('height')) > 0) {
        //Do something with element with height greater than 0
        cy.wrap($el).click() // If you want to click the element with height greater than 0
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [assertions](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should#Arguments) and [recursion](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/recursion) like this:

```
context('getElementByHeight', () => {
    it('getElementByHeight', () => {
        cy.get(`elementSelector`) //Yeilds array of the needed elements
            .then(elementsArray =>{
                function heightTestRecursion (elementIndex = 0) {
                    if (elementIndex >= elementsArray.length) {
                        throw new Error ('We could not find the needed element')
                    }
                    cy.wrap(elementsArray[elementIndex])
                        .should('be.visible') // yields the element
                        .should('have.css', 'height')// yields the value of the element height
                        .then(height => {
                            if (height !== 0) {
                                elementIndex++
                                return heightTestRecursion(elementIndex)
                            }
                            // Some code to run when the element height is zero
                        })
                }
                heightTestRecursion()
            })
    })
})
```

Comment: Recursion is only needed when the DOM is changed by an action in the test and a re-query is needed. You are just performing an `.each()` but with more complicated code.

Comment: I suppose you are correct, but my code is sure to do the work and stop when done and easy to understand. It is better to have long code that works than short you do not understand how to make work.